# Exact location of the torrc configuration file for Tor Browser Bundle

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I'm currently using the Tor Browser Bundle on a Debian 11 machine, I downloaded it from the Tor website.
I need to customize the ExitNodes, in order to do this I have to edit the torrc file.
I have found the file at the following location:

```
/home/xxxxx/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_it/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor
```

But the very first line of this file says:

```
This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
```

I tried to edit it anyway, but whenever I run the tor browser, the file is overwritten with the default and I lose my changes.
So I'm stuck here, any hint?

Comment: Did you close the Tor Browser before you edited the file?

Comment: yes I did, I can see that the torrc is being regenerated every time I open the browser, because the "Last modified" attribute of the file changes.

Comment: Specifically, it should be modified each time you **close** the Tor Browser, which is why I wanted to make sure that you didn't modify it while it's open, in which case it would be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your .torrc file on follow way:

- do a initial start of your Tor browser
- exit your Tor browser

Now you can add thinks like the follow on your .torrc file (before you start you Tor browser (that need to be configured before every start of Tor Browser. That means, the file will be overwritten by Tor:

```
EntryNodes {GB}, {FR}, {IT} StrictNodes 1

ExcludeNodes {??} StrictNodes 1 # the ?? will exclude some not clear define or bad stuff

ExitNodes {US} StrictNodes 1
```